# How to display a li at a time, once I click a button

Tags: jquery, css

Once I click the button I am trying to display an `li` and then if I click it again it displays the following `li`. My jQuery code doesn't work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.moments').on('click', 'button', function() {
    $(this).closest('.moments').find('.uniques').slideDown();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="moments">
  <button>Click Here</button>
  <ul class="uniques" type="circle">
    <li>1</li><br>
    <li>2</li><br>
    <li>3</li><br>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: br inside li, why  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to play around your `li`'s max-height for that.

Here I setup the class `active`, which will reveal whichever `li` we want.

Every time the user clicks on the button, I reveal the next `li` without the class `active`.

*PS : Also, get rid of those dirty `<br>`. They're scary.*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.moments').on('click', 'button', function() {
    $(this).closest('.moments').find('.uniques li:not(.active)').eq(0).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.uniques li{
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.uniques li.active{
  max-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="moments">
  <button>Click Here</button>
  <ul class="uniques" type="circle">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: and if I don't want to remove the current li displayed and just and the next one. I mean click - show 1, 2nd click - show 1 and 2, not just 2.

Comment: @Francesc  What should the button do once everything is displayed, then?

Comment: @Francesc I edited my answer so that the button shows another `li` on each click. If every `li` is already displayed, it does nothing.

Comment: Yes like this. Once we have every li displayed, the button doesn't work. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a `:visible` selector in jQuery. You take the last visible one, and then go to the next to slide it down.

```
$('.moments').on('click', 'button', function() {
    $('.uniques').find("li:visible:last").next().slideDown();
});
```